# How to show multiple markers on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I m new to google map API. My question is can we show multiple markers on the map using the API???

Comment: Please post some code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yes you can.  Just call the `new google.maps.Marker()` function for each marker location you want to add to your map.

I assume you've already got a map created, called 'map'.  This will add 2 markers to it.

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(24.696554,-81.328238),
    map: map
});

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.815155, -0.137072),
    map: map
});
```